# Get package name when installing from source

Tags: r, package

I know you can install a .tar.gz or .zip from source using the following.

```
install.packages(SOURCE_FILE, repos = NULL, type="source")
```

I want to be able to determine the name of the package that's being installed.  So for instance we could download this amazing package: https://github.com/Dasonk/findPackage/tarball/master?download.

This would give us a .tar.gz called `Dasonk-findPackage-61907b1.tar.gz`.  We could actually rename it to `beep.tar.gz` and still install as:

```
 install.packages("beep.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

How can I get the actual package's name that was installed.  I thought I could use `capture.output` but that does not seem to work either.  So after using `install.packages` I'd like to know `"findPackage"` was just installed.

Answer (score 1):

I hate this but it's all I could come up with:

```
package_name <- function(package) {
    temp <- tempdir()
    untar(package, exdir = temp)
    out <- c(read.dcf(list.files(temp, pattern="DESCRIPTION", 
        recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE), "Package"))
    unlink(temp, recursive = TRUE, force = FALSE)
    out
}

package_name("beep.tar.gz")
```

Comment: After poking around the package functions, I found `read.dcf` for reading `DESCRIPTION`: `read.dcf("path/to/DESCRIPTION", "Package")`.

Comment: After your `untar` command, you can simplify a little: `read.dcf(list.files(temp, pattern="DESCRIPTION", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE), "Package")`

Comment: @GSee I'll make changes to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to install the package, then I think the easiest way seems like just getting the list of installed packages before and after:

```
# Grab previously installed packages
start.packages <- installed.packages()[,1]

# Install your new package
install.packages("beep.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")

# Find all new packages
setdiff(installed.packages()[,1], start.packages)
```

Obvious downsides are that you need to install the new package, and that you'll also get all the newly installed dependencies.

Comment: Another downside is that if the package has already been installed, you'll get nothing (except for new dependencies, if any).